# R split/map from purrr combined with tidy from broom to get linear model statistics by group

Tags: r, linear-regression, purrr, tidy, broom

I found this code online at tidyverse.org at this [link](https://purrr.tidyverse.org):

```
mtcars %>%
  split(.$cyl) %>%
  map(~ lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .)) %>%
  map(summary) %>%
  map_dbl("r.squared")
```

[image]

The code works as expected. I'm now practicing with this same structure but using a long dataframe. You can see the code; it's mostly the same. First I convert to a tibble, add rownames for cars, select numeric variables, and make the dataframe a long data frame.

```
mtcars <- as_tibble(mtcars, rownames = 'car')

mtcars_numeric <- mtcars %>%
  select(car, mpg, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec) 

mtcars_long_numeric <- pivot_longer(mtcars_numeric, names_to = 'names', values_to = 'values', 3:7)


mtcars_long_numeric %>%
  split(.$names) %>%
  map(~ lm(mpg ~ values, data = .)) %>%
  map(summary) %>%
  map_df("r.squared") %>%
  pivot_longer(., names_to = 'explanatory_variable_to_mpg', values_to = 'r_squared', 1:5) %>%
  arrange(desc(r_squared))
```

[image]

But what about other model statistics like p-value? How do I extract that? If I just change "r.squared" to "p.value" it doesn't work. I've tried other variations like "p_value" and "pvalue" and it doesn't work. I also don't know how to find the right names for these objects.

[image]

I can create a linear model object and look at the r.squared in the summary and get the right value.

```
mtcars_linear_model <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)

summary(mtcars_linear_model)$r.squared
```

[image]

...But outside of this vignette I don't know how I would have known that r.squared existed in the summary of linear model. If I just type the dollar sign after the summary(lm) I get values that don't exist. (Is this a bug?)

[image]

Then I tried a different tactic. I can see that if I use broom and tidy the linear model object I have other statistics:

```
broom::tidy(mtcars_linear_model)
```

[image]

Is there any way to add the broom::tidy function to these data frames involving purrr:map? The purpose would be to figure out how to extract other model statistics like p-value. Also, how do I find a comprehensive list of items I can extract from the summary of a linear model object summary(lm)$'?'

The following code doesn't work. I tried a few variations like %>% tidy() or else to wrap tidy around map(summary) like this: tidy(map(summary)) but it doesn't work.

```
mtcars_long_numeric %>%
  split(.$names) %>%
  map(~ lm(mpg ~ values, data = .)) %>%
  map(summary) %>%
  tidy() %>% #### ????????
  map_df("r.squared") %>%
  pivot_longer(., names_to = 'explanatory_variable_to_mpg', values_to = 'r_squared', 1:5) %>%
  arrange(desc(r_squared))
```

Comment: For your question about what is an the output of summary for lm objects: The "Values" section of the documentation for the summary method for lm objects (`?summary.lm`) is a useful place to start. Since I invariably forget what I can pull out of the summary manually, I also use things like `names(summary(model))` and `str(summary(model))` to figure out what is in the output and what the names are.

Comment: As an aside, in a case where I know I might need to extract different things from the models I like to save the list of models as output. That way I don't have to refit all the models if I want to extract something new. How useful this is can depend on, e.g., how long models take to fit/how many groups you have. (Looks like I have an example of doing things this way in a [blog post](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2019/07/22/automate-model-fitting-with-loops/), where I make a list of models, check assumptions, and then extract output after that.)

Comment: @aosmith I'll definitely read that blog post of yours - thanks for sharing it. It looks like a great read considering the kind of R questions I have. Also, I understand that my own question/workflow here, from a scientific point-of-view, might be a little suspect - lining up all the model statistics for all groups side-by-side - because it would look like I'm hunting for a p-value instead of creating a research question and doing hypothesis testing. Part of what I'm doing here is trying to understand concise programming workflows and functions in tidyverse packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This?. You need to use `glance` instead of `tidy` for model statistics.

```r
mtcars_long_numeric %>% 
  nest_by(names) %>% 
  mutate(model = list(lm(mpg ~ values, data = data))) %>% 
  summarise(glance(model))
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'names'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 5 × 13
# Groups:   names [5]
  names r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic  p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC deviance df.residual  nobs
  <chr>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int> <int>
1 disp      0.718         0.709  3.25     76.5  9.38e-10     1  -82.1  170.  175.     317.          30    32
2 drat      0.464         0.446  4.49     26.0  1.78e- 5     1  -92.4  191.  195.     604.          30    32
3 hp        0.602         0.589  3.86     45.5  1.79e- 7     1  -87.6  181.  186.     448.          30    32
4 qsec      0.175         0.148  5.56      6.38 1.71e- 2     1  -99.3  205.  209.     929.          30    32
5 wt        0.753         0.745  3.05     91.4  1.29e-10     1  -80.0  166.  170.     278.          30    32
```

Comment: this is extremely concise that's awesome

Comment: is there a good heuristic for split(.$) vs nest_by() that you keep in mind?

Comment: I don't know. At the end all is trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Remember: the %>% command pipes the previous object or result to the first argument of the subsequent function or to the argument defined as a dot.

1. mtcars is turned into tibble with the line names turned into a variable;
2. the variables (columns) from car to qsec are selected;
3. the database is extended with variable names from 3 to 7 generating a variable named 'names';
4. the database is divided into a list by the variable previously defined as 'names';
5. the map function is used to map the elements of the list and apply the lm function in each database;
6. as the result of the models come out as elements of a list, the glance function is applied again through the mapping of the elements of the list to return the summary of the models.
7. the summaries of the models are just tables of one row dentro de uma lista. These tables can be concatenated through the bind_rows function to transform into a single dataframe.

```
mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = 'car') %>% 
  select_at(vars(car:qsec)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_to = 'names', values_to = 'values', cols = 3:7) %>% 
  split(.$names) %>%
  map(~ lm(mpg ~ values, data = .)) %>%
  map(broom::glance) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = 'names')
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?